# Python Seaborn Heatmap Turnoff main plot keep the cbar

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn, heatmap

I am drawing a sub-plot figures with each sub-plot is a heatmap. I turned off all cbars. Now I will plot cbar separately. While doing so, I am getting main plot. I don't want it. I want to turn if off.

My code:

```
df1 = 
Datetime        
2022-08-04 15:06:00     53.4    57.8
2022-08-04 15:07:00     54.3    57.0
2022-08-04 15:08:00     53.7    57.0
2022-08-04 15:09:00     54.3    57.2
2022-08-04 15:10:00     55.4    57.5
2023-10-21 14:00:00     43.9    35.2
2023-10-21 14:01:00     43.4    34.8
2023-10-21 14:02:00     43.4    34.7
2023-10-21 14:03:00     43.3    34.5
2023-10-21 14:04:00     42.7    33.9
# Heatmap: draw colorbar only, turn off the plot
sns.heatmap(np.reshape(df1.dropna().values.flatten(),(-1,1)),cbar=True,cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

Present output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]